# Ubuntu, install from USB without the ISO?

Tags: installation, 11.10, usb, iso

So, this is probably a quickie.

I've gotten a copy of Ubuntu 11.10 on a memory stick. The contents of the folder is similar to what I found in the .ISO of Ubuntu 12.04. My question to you now, is as follows:

I don't actually have the .ISO-file, but I have all the contents .. Can I still use it to install?

_ Edit:

I am indeed aware that this is an outdated version. The reason I cannot install a newer version, however, is because I am working offshore, and I have a 128/256 kbps internet connection here (Varies between the two). This connection is shared among the entire crew and computerized functions onboard, meaning an Ubuntu download would take days upon days, not to mention it would render the connection useless to anyone else. I simply have to use whatever I can get my hands on from other members of the crew.

Comment: Support for 11.10 officially ended already. Why not install a newer version?

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about an 'end of life' or old, unsupported version of Ubuntu

Comment: Sadly, I am at sea, and we're having a 256 kbps line divided among the crew and work machines. This means that a new download is out of the picture the next four weeks. I'll have to work with whatever I can get my hands on through my on board mates.

Answer (score 1):

If you got a copy of it on a USB then it should be bootable, but before you boot into it make sure you have set up a partition

Comment: Thanks for the tip. It doesn't seem to be bootable, though. It gives me an error saying I need to remove disks or other media .. I am currently researching the matter, to see if it's possible to work around that error. My other project at the moment is to burn the folders as an image (ISO), then burn it to a CD .. Fingers crossed :)

Answer (score 0):

Yes, On mac os you can move the contents to a folder (ubuntu) and then open terminal and type:
hdiutil makehybrid -o ubuntu.iso /path/to/ubuntu/folder

then you can burn it to a cd, put in the cd and type:

hdiutil burn ubuntu.iso

Comment: Does that make the ISO bootable? I am not sure you can reconstruct the original ISO just by the files.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't have a disk then download the iso file then download Daemon tools and it will let you format the iso to the usb so it will become bootable. Hope that helps! :D